# A word to express 'currently active'

Tags: single-word-requests

Suggest a word to express a task/thing has started, is running and is not yet complete.

Does *inchoate* fit?

Also, suggest a word to express completed/fully built thing/task.

Comment: For clarification purposes: you are asking for one word to say a task has begun and is in full operation, and one word to say when it is completed/ended/built. More context is needed, I'd say.

Comment: [How best to ask for words](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Yes. I'm asking for one word.

Comment: Running, on going, etc. etc.

Comment: @krishna: Then please read the advice I have linked to.

Comment: A typical use of inchoate is: _misty, inchoate suspicions that all is not well with the nation._ Yes, inchoate does mean unfinished, but what is unfinished is the form of something, not some process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are legal terms that relate

**[executory](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/executory)** - That which is yet to be fully executed or performed; that which remains to be carried into operation or effect; incomplete; depending upon a future performance or event. The opposite of executed.

**[executed](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/executed)** - adj. to have been completed. (Example: "it is an executed contract")

The problem with this pair is that *executed* can refer to something that is committed to but not yet actively begun, such as something that is to be started in the future.

More commonplace choices for the *running* concept are

> - in process
> - active
> - incomplete
> - continuing
> - advancing
> - evolving
> - unfolding
> - developing
> - proceeding
> - live
> - operative
> - in force
> - functioning

The choice very much depends on the field of the activity and the tone you are trying to convey. The choices for the *completed* concept would be as broad and varied.

Answer (score 5):

An **Ongoing** project

A task that is **underway**

Answer (score 2):

"Inchoate" is not suitable, meaning "just begun, undeveloped" (from Latin *choare* = to begin).

I suggest : functioning, in action, in operation ; "working" and "operative" could do, but don't imply "active in this moment" (I may have a working radio-set, but off right now).

Answer (score 1):

In Progress

Unfinished

Open-ended

Extant

Current